# Prove that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty (a_i-b_i)^p,$ where $a_i,b_i\in\mathbb{R},$ converges for $p\ge 2.$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Let $a_i,b_i\in\mathbb{R}$. If $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i^2$ and $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty b_i^2$ both converge, prove that $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty (a_i-b_i)^p,$ where $a_i,b_i\in\mathbb{R},$ converges for $p\ge 2.$

Here's my work:

Notice that it is sufficient to prove the result for $p=2.$

Hence for sufficiently large $i,|a_i-b_i|<1,$ and hence $|a_i-b_i|^p\le|a_i-b_i|^2.$ So $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty(a_i-b_i)^p$ is absolutely convergent and hence convergent.

$(a_i-b_i)^2 = a_i^2-2a_ib_i+b_i^2.$ Notice that $0\le (a_i-b_i)^2=2a_i^2+2b_i^2-(a_i+b_i)^2\le 2a_i^2+2b_i^2.$ Since $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i^2$ and $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty b_i^2$ are convergent, $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty (a_i-b_i)^2$ is convergent. $\;{\square}$

Comment: Your proof is correct.

Comment: @ClementYung do you think my proof could be shortened?

Comment: There are other ways to prove it, but they aren't much shorter than your method.

Comment: You can also directly deal with the general $p\geq 2$ by a similar trick:
$$
|a-b|^p \leq 2^p(|a|^p+|b|^p)
$$

Comment: @ClementC. how do you know that inequality is true? and even if you did, wouldn't you have to prove it?

Comment: $$\begin{align}|a-b|^p &\leq (|a|+|b|)^p = \sum_{k=0}^p \binom{p}{k} |a|^k |b|^{p-k} \\&\leq \sum_{k=0}^p \binom{p}{k} \max(|a|,|b|)^k \max(|a|,|b|)^{p-k}
= \sum_{k=0}^p \binom{p}{k} \max(|a|,|b|)^p\\
&= 2^p \max(|a|,|b|)^p
\leq 2^p (|a|^p+|b|^p)\end{align}$$ @GerardWilliamson (Just wanted to mention it as it's useful to know, and simple to show.)